# AWS Data Exchange returing timeout error when accessed from lambda function that is within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When a Lambda is attached to one (or more) VPC subnets, the post call to data exchange api times out. And when the Lambda is detached from all subnets, then this post call succeeds. This is happening consistently in golang Lambda environment.

In my use case, I am accessing Redis from Lambda, and Redis is accessible only from within the VPC.

Error message:
error=RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data-sets: dial tcp 52.85.148.96:443: i/o timeout

Comment: your lambda is in private subnet?

Comment: yes @Marcin lambda is in private subnet.

Comment: So that's why probably it can't communicate with dataexchenge endpoint. Have you setup NAT gateway in your VPC?

Comment: No, i have not setup NAT gateway right now. Does NAT gateway needed for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AWS Lambda function running in a VPC will never be assigned a public IP address. So in order for the Lambda function to access resources that exist outside the VPC, such as the AWS Data Exchange service, the VPC will need to be configured with a NAT Gateway that provides Internet access to the private subnet(s) the Lambda function is deployed to.

Comment: I've configure the NAT Gateway. Still having the issue. 
Its looks there is some issue with the DNS.

Thanks.

Comment: @GhulamMustafa Make sure the Lambda's private subnet has a route configured to the NAT gateway.

Comment: Thats configured. It seems to be the DNS issue. When i check the data exchange server IP using **nslookup dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com**
the results are:
 
`Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 13.227.185.20
Name: dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 13.227.185.86
Name: dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 13.227.185.126
Name: dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 13.227.185.35 

`

but in Lambda error logs the IP is **52.85.148.96** .